# Android load listviews at end of scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, handler

I want to implement functionality where a listview loads a set number of views, but at the end of the scrolling it has a spinner in that view, while it loads more views

the official android twitter app has something like this, where it shows you old messages from your timeline but at the bottom of the list it will load more after running a spinner. you can still scroll up and down while this thread is happening without breaking anything

how would this be done? insight appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think by spinner  u mean blocking  screen ?
anyways what u  need is pretty common, just search for listview implementation in android
here is one of the link i still had:
http://blog.zjor.ru/2010/12/loading-list-data-asynchronously-in.html

also check this if u really want to go to that extent ;)

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

Answer (score 1):

basically, it would probably be something like:

Load some data (use a limit)

When you enter the bindView of your last element, change your limit (may be by joining the cursor to another one)

Comment: bindView being the part in your Adapter where you put values into views. When you are binding the last element of your content, you can show a progressbar and load more content